# why different download way result in different display?

Tags: python

When i down the file on the web with my firefox,
http://quotes.money.163.com/service/lrb_000559.html
it looks fine in my EXCEL.

[image]

When i down the file with my python code,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="http://quotes.money.163.com/service/lrb_000559.html"
html=urlopen(url)       
outfile=open("g:\\000559.csv","w")
outfile.write(html.read().decode("gbk"))
outfile.close()
```

it looks stange, when open it with my EXCEL,there is one line filled with proper content ,and one line filled with blank ,you can try it in your pc.
Why will  different download way result in different  display ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 'b' flag to the file open, i.e. change this:

```
outfile=open("g:\\000559.csv","w")
```

To this:

```
outfile=open("g:\\000559.csv","wb")
```

Explanation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). The original file had a `\r\n`, and Python is converting the `\n` to `\r\n`, meaning you have an extra carriage return at the end of every line (`\r\r\n`).

Comment: it is the soft to decide how to dispaly  `\r\r\n`,when i open the two files which dowloaded by different download way ,there is the same dispaly in agenda ,but different dispaly in EXCEL.

Comment: Yes, each software displays differently. You can see the line endings in a text editor like Notepad++ (View > Show Symbol).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that line endings are changed when decoding and writing the result in python. Try using a binary file instead. Off the top of my head, I think it would go something like this:

```
outfile=open("g:\\000559.csv","wb")
outfile.write(html.read())
```